# I work miracles. What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I go from water to stone,
>
> I am the shades of a rainbow,
>
> I help the blind see,
>
> I help the thirsty drink,
>
> What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Very clever riddle +1

Comment: Thanks! Although I regret accepting the answer so quickly. I know other stackexchange sites prefer to wait a day, but I was so excited to see someone get the answer right.
Is it alright that I accepted the answer so quickly?

Comment: Yes, absolutely fine. The only reasons I know of to delay acceptance are: (1) for some reason you think an *even better* answer might come along, (2) you want more people to view the question (fewer will look if it's been solved, (3) accepting answers is a chore, so you leave them for a while and do them in batches. Those are all fine, but all else being equal it's good to accept promptly.

Comment: I found [this question](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4375/how-fast-should-i-accept-a-correct-answer) on meta for you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Is it

> Glass?

I go from water to stone

> <s>Water on stone makes sand, which is used to make glass.</s>
> Glass starts out as a liquid and is cooled into a solid. (Credit Mart10)

I am the shades of a rainbow

> A glass prism can be used to make a rainbow effect.

I help the blind see

> You can wear glasses.

I help the thirsty drink

> You can drink from a glass.

Comment: Aw beat me to it

Comment: For water to stone, i was going to say liquid state to solid state

Comment: Yeah, I too think @Mart10 's idea of molten glass being cooled into hard glass is probably more relevant. And your answer feels the most appropriate!

Comment: This is definitely what I was thinking of! :) Although after clicking accept, I realise maybe I should have waited. Puzzling seems a bit different to the other forums, not sure if I should have accepted ASAP or wait until tomorrow.

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose I don't know either, I'm new here too. Good riddle though!

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose - if you find that your puzzle is bringing in innovative answers (like Shinji Wins' answer), then you can choose to keep it open longer. Also, bear in mind that people across the globe use PSE, so in deference to timezones you might wish to keep it open for several hours to a day even if its solved. Note that this is not a rule or a stringent guideline, its more of my opinion.

Answer (score 18):

Is it a

> wave?

Because

> waves crash against stones 
>  sounds in pedestrian crossing signal help blind people cross the street and so "see" traffic (sound is a wave) 
>  rainbows are made up of several **WAVE**lengths 
>  waves help you drink water since it goes directly in your face

Comment: I like the thought process you have here, but I was thinking of something a bit less abstract.

Comment: my last explaination is a bit far-fetched though ^^  good riddle ;)

Comment: +1 for last line :D

Answer (score 10):

Are you

> Water itself?

I go from water to stone

> Water turns into ice, a solid state. (credit to puzzledPig)

I am the shades of a rainbow

> Rainbows are light diffracting off water moisture in the air.

I help the blind see

> Eyelids spread water over the eyes to protect them, and without it you can end up with dry eye, leaving them vulnerable to infection.

I help the thirsty drink

> Pretty self explanatory. You drink water.

Comment: The first clue could maybe also refer to the frozen form?

Comment: I think you might be right there actually.

Comment: The "help the blind to see" feels like a stretch to me, but good thinking! Not what I had in mind though.

Comment: @ErdrikIronrose Frankly I find the “help the blind to see” a stretch in your accepted answer too. :-) It's more “help the mildly visually impaired (who can already see) to see better”.